# Writing to a new window

Tags: gwt, new-window

Im trying to get some simple javascript working in gwt but keep failing.

**The code:**

```
public static native void createWindow() /*-{   
    var wndRef = $wnd.open('','edit');
    var divTag = document.createElement("div");        
        divTag.id = "div1";

        divTag.setAttribute("align","center");    
        divTag.style.margin = "0px auto";

        divTag.innerHTML = "blah blah blah";

        wndRef.document.body.appendChild(divTag);
    }-*/;
```

I am trying to open a new window and write content to it

**The problem:**
Currently this code opens a new window but its empty.

How do i write content to it ? am i doing something wrong or am i expecting too much from gwt?

**Context:** My end goal is to open a new Window and have my form panel and various widgets inserted in to it via java methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GWT is compiled to Javascript, so GWT can do what JS can do.

If you want to open a new window and inject some content to it then this is the right way:

```
var win = window.open("", "win", "width=300,height=200"); // a window object
win.document.open("text/html", "replace");
win.document.write("<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>New Document</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>Hello, world!</BODY></HTML>");
win.document.close();
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, i got it working that way was curious to know why the technique above doesnt work i thought i was doing the same thing only using function calls on element and document.

Comment: Thanks Peter, this works great on all browsers except IE 10 (Surprise! Surprise). Would you have a solution for that?